# Read Only access to subfolder inside a folder in a library

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hello community.

I have a Private Site on SharePoint 365. I have Documents Library. Inside this library I have a folder called Example and inside this folder another folder called Example1. It looks like this:

MySite >> Documents >> Example >> Example1

I've granted "Can edit" access to a user on Example folder. So the user can upload a document in this folder. But now I want this user to read only on Example1 subfolder so the user can not upload any document, just read it. Despite I granted "Can view" access to Example1 folder and broke inherits permission, the user still can upload documents in it. When I check the user permissions, I can see it has Read permission (given directly) and Contribute (which I think is still inherited by the Example parent folder).

Thanks in advanced.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

After 'Break permission inheritance', did you missed the below step ?

Removing the existing users/groups.
[image]

Comment: I only allowed Read but Contribute is still there.

Answer (score 0):

In the unique permission for Example1, you should remove users from contribute group. If users have both read and contribute permisson, SharePoint recognizes they have contribute permissions by default.

Comment: Can you show the steps to revoke Contribute permission in a subfolder for a user? I have not found this.

Comment: I can not see the Contribute group you're talking about.

Comment: Apologies as I rushed writing the above and introduced confusion. I means that remove the user from a group with contribute permisison.